# Why website link doesn't show in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref, links

I don't know why the bib reference of website link does not show up. Any solutions? Thanks.

```
@article{brunet2005grant,
  title={Grant funding to state and local governments and systematic assessment of vulnerability},
  author={Brunet, A.},
  year={2005},
  note = {Accessed August 2013},
  howpublished={\url{http://create.usc.edu/research/50788.pdf}}
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without having a full MWE, as also requested by @jubobs, it's not possible to diagnose fully what's going on. Do you use BibTeX or biblatex, by the way? From a glance at your bib entry, it looks like you're abusing the `@article` entry type: you're not providing a `journal` (or `journaltitle`) field, yet you provide a `howpublished` field. `howpublished` fields are generally ignored by most bibliography styles (both traditional BibTeX and bibLaTeX) for entries of type `@article`. You may want to change the entry type to `@misc` and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. When I use '@misc' as Mico suggested, it works. Btw, '@techreport' does not work.

Answer (score 10):

Note that in most bib styles I'm familiar with, the `howpublished` field is ignored for entries of type `@article`; this explains why the contents of this field don't show up if you use the `@article` entry type.

From a visit to the web page provided in your code, it appears that the piece you're looking to reference is a numbered technical report rather than an article published in a journal. Thus, you really shouldn't be using the `@article` entry type; instead, I suggest you use the `@techreport` entry type. The entry should therefore probably look something like this:

```
@techreport{brunet2005grant,
  author      = "A. Brunet",
  title       = "Grant funding to state and local governments 
                 and systematic assessment of vulnerability",
  year        = 2005,
  institution = "University of Southern California",
  type        = "CREATE Report",
  number      = "05-018",
  url         = "http://create.usc.edu/research/50788.pdf",
  note        = "Accessed August 2013", 
}
```

This setup assumes that you're using biblatex or `BibTeX` along with a reasonably modern bibliography style (such as `plainnat`) that recognizes the `url` field type. (If you use a bib style that doesn't recognize the `url` field type, you should combine the contents of the `url` and `note` fields into a single field of type `note`, e.g., `note = {\url{http://create.usc.edu/research/50788.pdf}, accessed August 2013},` )

In the following example, I assume you're using BibTeX along with the `plainnat` bibliography style as well as the `natbib` and `hyperref` packages. You'll get the following output after running `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, and `pdflatex` twice more:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % use whatever bib style is right for you
\begin{document}
\cite{brunet2005grant}
\bibliography{create} % if the entry is in a file called 'create.bib'...
\end{document}
```

If you don't load the `hyperref` package, you should make sure to load the `url` package so that the URL field will be typeset correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it is a proper article which is also available online like a paper in a journal at springerlink.

If you are using `biblatex` then try the `url` field:

```
@article{brunet2005grant,
  title={Grant funding to state and local governments and systematic assessment of vulnerability},
  author={Brunet, A.},
  year={2005},
  urldate = {2013-08}, <---- CHANGE
  url={http://create.usc.edu/research/50788.pdf} <---- CHANGE
}
```

The `url` field in an optional field, here's a screenshot of the `biblatex` package manual:

[image]

Comment: With no additional info from the OP *and* Mico's comment regarding the "abuse" of the `@article` type, this doesn't seem like good advice.

Comment: Hi. Why is that an abuse? The article type in biblatex has the url field as an optional field as you can read in the biblatex manual.

Comment: Using the `@article` entry type for a piece that has not been published in a journal or similar outlet is unfortunate, to say the least. A tip-off that the `@article` type should not be used for the entry at hand is that one of its *required* fields, viz., `journal` (biblatex: `journaltitle`), is missing. The piece to be referenced happens to be a working paper. For working papers and the like, one should use the entry type `@techreport`, not `@article`.

Comment: Hi. I understood the problem differently. I thought that it is an proper article which is also available online like a paper in a journal at springerlink. I guess that caused the confusion.